# RTC - Flowing changes from one stream to another

Tags: eclipse, branching-and-merging, rtc

I have two streams; a main stream and an r&d stream. I want change sets delivered to the main stream to also flow to the r&d stream. I have a process to achieve this however it is not altogether intuitive and prone to error.

This is my current process;

- Create repository workspace for stream main
- Create repository workspace for stream r&d
- Add the main stream as a flow target in my r&d repository workspace.
- Set the new main stream flow target as 'current' and 'default'
- Accept the incoming change set into my r&d workspace (I don't touch the outgoing change sets)
- Remove the main stream flow target from my r&d repository workspace
- Deliver the change sets accepted in the previous steps to the r&d stream

Is there a cleaner approach which would simply allow me to have the changes flowing into my r&d repository workspace without the need to constantly add the main stream flow target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article "[How to keep your streams flowing smoothly](https://jazz.net/library/article/649)" comes to mind.

A **[post-build deliver step](https://jazz.net/library/article/649#Tip2)** would automate the delivery from main stream to r&d stream.

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/3.0/scm-deliver-streams/images/deliver_single_component.png]

You might need to adapt that process, but it is one way of automating a deliver between streams.

Comment: does this option only work when using the RTC build engine? I'm using Jenkins to connect and build my RTC project however when i try the post deliver option it does'nt work. I checked the build result and there is no mention of the post-deliver step succeeding

Comment: @niloc yes, but Jenkins wouldn't know about it: it is done with RTC (RTC4 and the official IBM RTC plugin for Jenkins).

Answer (score 2):

Re: Is there a cleaner approach which would simply allow me to have the changes flowing into my r&d repository workspace without the need to constantly add the main stream flow target?

To simplify your manual syncing of streams, you don't need to explicitly add/remove the main stream to your r&d repository workspace list of flow targets.  In the Pending Changes view, if you are showing your r&d repository workspace, you can select "Change Flow Target..." from the context menu and easily switch between main and r&d.  This will add the stream to the list of flow targets and set it as current.  The default flow target is really only important for a build workspace.

I noticed you also created a repository workspace off the main stream, but don't mention it in your process.  It is really unnecessary, as you're only using one repository workspace.

Scott

Comment: thanks @ScottCowan, the second repository workspace is only required if i need to make changes directly on the main stream.